# Get the latest checked-in version (document) of a document from SP 2010 doc library

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, document-versioning

I have a document library with versioning enabled in SharePoint 2010. 
I want to get the file which is checked-in and for any checked-out file, i need to get its latest checked-in version (document).
I am using c# server side object model on SharePoint 2010.
Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] of your attempt so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could help. It will iterate through all items in the list and if the item is Checked Out it will find latest Published version.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite("https://sharepoint.domain.com"))
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPList list = web.GetList($"{web.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/')}/DocumentLibrary");
            SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(new SPQuery());

            foreach (SPListItem item in items)
            {
                object checkedOutTo = item[SPBuiltInFieldId.CheckoutUser];
                if (checkedOutTo == null)
                {
                    // Latest version
                    Console.WriteLine($"{item.ID} | {item.Versions[0].VersionLabel}");

                    // Here are bytes of the file itself
                    byte[] bytes = item.File.OpenBinary();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Find latest published version
                    SPFileVersion version = item.File.Versions
                        .Cast<SPFileVersion>()
                        .OrderByDescending(v => v.ID)
                        .Where(v => v.Level == SPFileLevel.Published)
                        .FirstOrDefault();

                    if (version != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"{item.ID} | {version.VersionLabel} | {checkedOutTo}");

                        // Here are bytes of the file itself
                        byte[] bytes = version.OpenBinary();
                    }
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine($"{item.ID} | No published version | {checkedOutTo}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Lukas thanks for your valuable response! This will give me only the version number whereas i need a actual document of that version number.

Comment: Thanks Lukas for your valuable help! Appreciate your time and help!